# How to remove iframe tag between html tag and head tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

**I want to remove the iframe that is appearing between html and head tag. It do not appear in the desktop version. Whenever I open site on mobile version, it appears between HTML and Head tag.**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  
  <iframe scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent !important; display: block !important; z-index: 2147483637 !important; border: none !important; width: 320px !important; height: 66.6667px !important; position: fixed !important; bottom: 0px !important; left: 0px !important;"></iframe>
  
  <head id="ctl00_headerMaster">
  <title>How to get iframe between html tag and head tag</title>
    
  </head>
  
  <body id="ctl00_edubody">
 
    <h1>How to get iframe between html tag and head tag</h1>
    
    
  </body>
  
 </html>
```

Comment: No idea why, it's not valid html. Need to fix the source

Comment: the `<title>` and `<h1>` in that snippet of code says `How to get iframe between html tag and head tag` - does that mean you wanted it there at some stage?

Comment: `$('html > iframe').eq(0).remove();`

Comment: Yes I want to remove it. The title tag content is by mistaken written.

Comment: Actually there are many iframes too in the body tag, But I want to remove between HTML and Head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's invalid to put `iframe` as the direct child of `HTML` tag. We can't predict how it handles by the browser so the below code may fail.

---

Use [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to get the `iframe` and remove using [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

```
$('head').prevAll('iframe').remove();
```

---

Or get the direct child of `HTML` tag and remove it.

```
$('html > iframe:first-child').remove();
```

Comment: no guarantees this will work cross browser since it's invalid putting the frame there and how browser handles that could be unpredicable

Comment: Your second code is not responsive in the case when we are using iframes in a single page and iframe is calling files of the same domain. What you think ? @Pranav C Balan.